# react-native-camera convert Image base64 to jpeg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, base64, react-native-camera

I've managed to use `react-native-camera` to take an image then display it in the `<Image>` element, then send the image's **base64** string back to my back-end, however, I can't manage to display the image once it is on my back-end because it's in base64, the image is displayed properly in the `<Image>` element with the `src` attribute set in the `data:image/jpeg;base64,{BASE64_HERE}` format.

Could you guide me through to make this work?

Here's my code

```
'use strict';

import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import {RNCamera} from 'react-native-camera';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

class App extends PureComponent {

    state = {
        img: false,
        b64: null,
    }

  render() {
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>

        <RNCamera
          ref={ref => {
            this.camera = ref;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.front}
          flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
          androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use camera',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={null}
          onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={null}
        />

        <View style={{flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}
            style={styles.capture}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 14}}> SNAP </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>

        {this.state.img ? (
                <Image
                    source={{
                        isStatic: true,
                        uri: this.state.b64,
                    }}
                    style={{height: 100, width:100}}
        /> ) : null }

      </View>
    );
  }

    takePicture = async () => {
        if (this.camera) {
            const options = {quality: 0.5, base64: true};
            const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
                if (request.readyState !== 4) {
                    return;
                }

                if (request.status === 200) {
                    alert('success');
                } else {
                    alert('error' + JSON.stringify(e));
                }
            };



            request.open('POST', 'http://myurl/get_img.php');
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


            var filepath = data.uri.split('//')[1];
            var imageUriBase64 = await RNFS.readFile(filepath, 'base64');


            this.setState({b64: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageUriBase64, img: true});

            request.send('data=' + imageUriBase64);



        }

    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  preview: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  },
  capture: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    margin: 20,
  },
});


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the fact that you are trying to access the **data.uri** property when **base64** option is set to **true**. Can you check the value of **data.uri**?

It’s  possible that **data.uri** is **undefined** when base64 is true, which leads **RNFS.readFile** to fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to display your image when it is fetched from backend (the code snippet not provided here) then maybe it is coming in compressed form or you maybe not adding the prefix `'data:image/jpeg;base64,'`